# Toggle classes when triggered by anchor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4.1 to build a collapsible element.

```
<div class="card text-left mb-3 mt-3">
  <div class="card-head p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h4>How do we get started?</h4>
    <a id="ToggleElement" class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    content...
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I change the class from caret-down when closed to caret-up when open.

I know I can use something kind of like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(){
        // Code to swap the classes
    }
    $('#ToggleElement').click(changeClass);
</script>
```

What do I need to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

- Change your initial class from to make the icon work properly. (remove 's' from fa<strike>s</strike>)

  `fas fa-caret-down` to `fa fa-caret-down`

```html
<a id="ToggleElement" class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

### Second

- Add the js `<script>` logic to toggle the class when it is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ToggleElement").on("click", function() {
    $("#ToggleElement>i.fa-caret-down").toggleClass('fa-caret-up');
  });
});
```

- This will add the 'on click' listener and toggle the fa-caret-up class whenever element with **id** `ToggleElement` was clicked.

### Working example here!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card text-left mb-3 mt-3">
      <div class="dropdown card-head p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h4>How do we get started?</h4>
        <a id="ToggleElement" data-toggle="collapse" class="" href="#collapse1"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Content1
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body">
          Content2
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body">
          Content3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#ToggleElement").on("click", function() {
        $("#ToggleElement>i.fa-caret-down").toggleClass('fa-caret-up');
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toggleClass` of jQuery.

```
function changeClass(event) {
  $(event.target).find('i.fas').toggleClass('fa-caret-down');
  $(event.target).find('i.fas').toggleClass('fa-caret-up');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle caret without JavaScript workaround.

make both up and down displayed, and hide each of them when both parent elements have `collapsed`  or not.

```css
:not(.collapsed) > i.fas.fa-caret-down {
  display: none;
}

.collapsed > i.fas.fa-caret-up {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```